# Can I add Daisy UI plugin to my django project? If yes , Please how do I do it?

Tags: django, tailwind-css, daisyui

I have already installed tailwind CSS to my django project and it works just fine,

I tried using the documentation procedure I saw at the daisyui website

`npm i daisyui`

and I also added the plugin to my tailwin.config.js file also

`module.exports = { //... plugins: [require("daisyui")], }`

Comment: did you figure out the problem?